# Visual Studio Code consume mucha ram y no abre proyectos

Tags: web, vscode

he estado teniendo problemas con VS Code, de un día para otro no abre los proyectos de páginas web, doy clic en serve project y la ram va subiendo hasta que se ocupa el 99% y el disco va al 100%, el proyecto no carga y se congela todo, alguno sabrá a qué pueda deberse?
Estoy trabajando con un procesador i7-4790, 8 de ram y disco mecánico, si eso ayuda.
Gracias de cualquier modo.

Comment: Actualización: Probé el mismo proyecto en una computadora con un Ryzen 5 3450u, 16 gb de ram y SSD, es el mismo problema.

Comment: Si creas un proyecto en blanco y NO te pasa lo mismo el problema es de tu proyecto no de VS. Dado el caso deberás depurar y ver que porción de código es el que te está consumiendo la ram

Comment: Es un proyecto con el que llevo más o menos un mes, y apenas fue cuando me empezó a dar problemas, he trabajado con proyectos más pesados y grandes y parece que el problema es solo con ese proyecto en específico, podrías darme una idea de qué partes del código podrían consumir la memoria?

Comment: Lo típico es una función recursiva que no se detiene. O algo más complejo como que la función A llame a B que llama a C y esta última vuelve a llamar A. Un while(true) también puede ser, una conexión a algo (FTP, base de datos, HTTP) que no conecta entonces vuelve a tratar de conectar provocando un bucle infinito. Lo primero que haría sería analizar el código manualmente, si tú dices que el problema pasa al iniciar, por muy grande que sea tu proyecto no se ejecuta todo a la vez, entonces comenzaría desde el program.cs. Comentaría partes del código y vería si soluciona el problema

Comment: Si nada funciona, puedes ir al menú "Depurar" y luego "Generador de perfiles de rendimiento" Ahí hay herramientas que deberían ayudarte, yo no las he utilizado nunca así no puedo darte más detalle sobre ellas

Comment: Lo intentaré, gracias por tu ayuda!